# Get unique random number within range on each call

Tags: algorithm, random, time-complexity, unique, class-design

I came across this question where the goal is to design a class with two methods - `get()` and `set_range(x, y)`.

The behavior of both the methods is explained in the comments below & there are examples too.

```
class UniqueRandomGenerator {
  int start, end;

  public:
    int get() {
      // Returns a unique random number in the range [start, end].

      // Every call should return a different random number unless there 
      // is no number left to be returned within the range [start, end].

      // When all numbers within [start, end] are already returned at least once,
      // the range is reset and then it is ok to return the previously returned 
      // number.
    }

    void set_range(int s, int e) {
      // Update the range [start, end] to be [s, e].

      // However, the random numbers returned by get() should still be unique. 
      // Only when there is no number left in [s, e], we can repeat the numbers.
    }

};
```

For example:

```
set_range(5, 8);
get(); // returns one of {5, 6, 7, 8}. Say it returns 6
set_range(3, 6);
get(); // must return one of {3, 4, 5}. Note that 6 is not there because it 
       // returned previously. Say it returns 3.
get(); // One of {4, 5}. Say 4.
get(); // One of {5}. Must be 5.
get(); // Because there is no number left, range gets reset. Now one of {3, 4, 5, 6}
       // should be returned.
```

- If there is only a `get()` operation to support & the range is
  constant

**Approach 1 -**
I can shuffle the array once and keep returning the next number from the array. When I reach the end, I would shuffle the array again and start returning the number from the beginning.

**Approach 2 -**
I can add numbers from [start, end] into the array and randomly generate an index between `0` to `array.size()-1`. Return the number at that index. Swap that index with the last index and then decrement the size of the array.

In both of the above approaches, there is a `O(n)` cost upfront even if the amortized time complexity is `O(1)` for each `get()`. If there are very few `get()` calls, then upfront `O(n)` is not desirable.

*Is there a way to divide that upfront cost over multiple `get()` calls?*

**Approach 3 -**
I can have a set where I can track all the returned numbers. Initially, it will be empty. I can generate a random number and see if it is present in the set. If it is not present, I will add it to set and return it. Otherwise, I will generate another number.

The problem with this approach is that there is no upper bound to how many times will I have to generate random numbers until I find a unique one.

---

All the above approaches only work, if at all, when the range is constant. The addition of `set_range()` makes it a lot more complex according to me.

*What are the efficient ways of handling both `get()` and `set_range()` calls?*

Comment: For your approach 3 you would enter an infinite loop if all the values have in fact been generated. --- Instead of doing repeated random probes like that you could iterate the interval starting from the initial (taken) random candidate (wrapping around at the end as needed) until you find one that's free, or you're back to the original, which means that the range is exhausted and must be reset.

Comment: For approach 1, you could spread the upfront cost by just doing one step of a Fisher-Yates shuffle before each `get()`.  However, that may well be slower than using a built in `array.shuffle()` method.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I will be able to recognize when all values are generated fairly easily because I will have a set of all values returned so far. I am not concerned about the infinite loop, it's more about the time required to find the unique one if there exists one.